# Configure Servlet Context variable

Tags: java, servlets

How I ensure that whether is entered variable sore to the context or not?

```
//While entered value //

    List list = (List)request.getParameter("title");
    getServletContext().setAttribute("title",list);

//Retrieve entered value//

    String value = (String) getServletcontext().getParameter("title");
    PrintWriter pw. response.getWriter():

    pw.println(""+value):
```

Comment: The question isn't clear, if you set an attribute in the context, you call `getAttribute` to get it back. Testing that is basically testing your container.

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke

```
List titleList = (List)getServletcontext().getAttribute("title")
```

Check `titleList` for correct values. It will return `null` if there no `attribute` by the name.

See [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html)

Comment: I haven't get null it's retrieve entered value but I want to know is it stored in context or not.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use getAttribute because you are setting attributes using setAttribute method

Comment: Thank You sir , I want become a great and successful Java Developer and I want Java Code become my passion .so what I should be do I want anyhow . Help me please. Thank you , you give me your invaluable time. Thank You

Comment: You hv to read java book like effective java..and tk part in google code jam..by the way did my answer work for you? If yes, pls accept it so other people cn tk benefit from you.